# How can I remove href attribute from anchor tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to remove or disable anchor tag attribute which comes under `<div class="removetag">` class from JavaScript without giving specific `id` to one anchor tag we can use div class for that.

Please help me how to I can do this thing.

**My code**

```
<div class="removetag">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>

<div class="notremove">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>
```

Comment: already tried `querySelectoAll` + `forEach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
document.querySelector('.removetag a').removeAttribute('href')
```

Comment: by using this working i have also one doubt if we have multiple anchor tag in div then how to we can do this to on specify anchor tag

Comment: as other people say, you could try querySelectorAll with forEach. If you want do it to specify anchor tag, the tag have to have some special things that other tag don't have. For example, index or className.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged the question with `jQuery`, you can solve your problem this way:

```js
$(".removetag a").removeAttr("href");
```

Demo

```js
$(".removetag a").removeAttr("href");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="removetag">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>

<div class="notremove">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to remove a an attribute you should use `removeAttribute('attributeName')`: `removeAttribute('href')`

to select a class use `querySelector`. However this will only return the first element with this class. To get all elements with this class you need to use `querySelectorAll` and use `forEach` to give a command to all of those elements.

```js
var removetag = document.querySelectorAll('.removetag a');
removetag.forEach(el => el.removeAttribute('href'));
```

```html
<div class="removetag">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>

<div class="notremove">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>

<div class="removetag">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>

<div class="notremove">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove href attribute we can simply use `dom.removeAttribute("href")`.
And if you want to remove attribute of hyperlinks with their parent div's class name then you can use `docunent.querySelector()`  Or `document.querySelectorAll()`.

In your case you can do like:

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.removetag a'),
  i;

for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  a[i].removeAttribute("href");
}
```

```html
<div class="removetag">

  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>

<div class="notremove">
  <a href="google.com"> google </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you have may typos within your code. Beside of that there is no reason to use a "long and complicated" irretation if you could simply use `forEach` which as a side effect consumes far less computing power.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with a `querySelector` and `el.removeAttribute`:

```
let removeHrefTarget = document.querySelector(".removeatag a"); //select the element that has the according class
removeHrefTarget.removeAttribute("href"); //remove the href-attribute from that element
```

But you may want to consider the possibility of having more than one element from which you want to remove the href. To do so you can use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a node list of all elements that match your criteria. Then loop through all elements in the list and remove the attribute for each of these:

```
let removeHrefTargets = document.querySelectorAll(".removeatag a"); //select all elements that have the according class
removeHrefTargets.forEach((el) => { //loop through each of these elements
    el.removeAttribute("href"); //remove the href attribute
})
```

**Edit:**
If you want to take this a step further you can also create a reusable function. This can be used whenever you want to remove any attribute from any element.

```
const removeAttribute = (selector, attribute) => {
    let removeAttributeTargets = document.querySelectorAll(selector); //select all elements that have the according class
    removeAttributeTargets.forEach((el) => { //loop through each of these elements
        el.removeAttribute(attribute); //remove the href attribute
    });
};
```

You can call this function with any selector (e.g. #id or .class or tag) like this:

```
removeAttribute(".myclass", "style");
```

Hope this helps :)